# How to check value in table by JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. I would like to check if the date field is empty or not. The function does nothing. Could someone help me? Thanks.

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <td>date</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr name = "table">
                <td class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="message"/>
                </td>
        </tbody>
</thead>

function validate() {
    var date = document.table.message.value;
        if(date == "")
            alert("Wrong value in message field");
    };
};
```

Comment: Where is `validate()` being called?

Comment: Where is your `table` tag?  Why do you close `thead` twice?

Comment: Does the date input need to be inside a table? if so, do you need to check each table cell with a a date input?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. Currently both your HTML and JavaScript are incomplete and invalid, so reproducing the problem is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use this code.

```
if(document.getElementById("message").value == ""){
   alert("No value given!");
}
```